# HTML picture in the background, making the picture smaller out of the middle, when the screen size change

Tags: html, css

I am quite new in HTML programming, so I try new things out every time. Now I got to a little problem and I would need your help. 
I have a .png picture in the background of my HTML-file. And if I make the size of the screen smaller, the picture cuts of on the sides.

`background: url(img/Website_Background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;`

So here my question, how is it possible, that the the middle part of the picture goes away (size of the picture is going to be smaller out of the middle), so that the part on the right and left side stays. 
Hopefully my description was understandable.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Sadly I don't seem to understand your issue. Could you provide us with some examples to explain this further? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the `fixed` component of `background`

Comment: Maybe you just want to try `background-size: contain;`

Comment: This can be done by using two containers for the picture, one that shows the left edge and another that shows the right edge. Make each container take up half of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url("img/Website_Background.png");
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
```

You should be good.